# Why are JavaScript Arguments objects mutated by assignment to parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

What is the rationale behind this behaviour?

```
function f(x) {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  x = 42;
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

f(1);
// => 1
// => 42
```

Perhaps this was a genuine mistake. Which section of the ECMAScript specification defines this behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, in strict mode, this does *not* happen as [you can see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler).

If you read section 10.6 of the [ECMA Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), in particular Note 1, you'll see:

> For non-strict mode functions the array index (defined in 15.4) named data properties of an arguments object 
>   whose numeric name values are less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding function object initially 
>   share their values with the corresponding argument bindings in the function‘s execution context. This means that changing 
>   the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa. This correspondence is broken if 
>   such a property is deleted and then redefined or if the property is changed into an accessor property. For strict mode 
>   functions, the values of the arguments object‘s properties are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and 
>   there is no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal parameter values.

In short, what this is saying is that, in non-strict mode, named function parameters operate as aliases for items in the `arguments` object. Thus, changing the value of a named parameter will change the value of the equivalent `arguments` item and vice versa. This is not a mistake. This is expected behaviour.

As an editorial, it's probably not a good idea to rely on this behaviour as it can lead to some very confusing code. Also, such code, if executed in strict mode, would not longer work.

Comment: Curious as to the reason for the downvote - would love to improve the answer where possible.

Answer (score 8):

Altering `x` is reflected in `arguments[0]` because indexes of `arguments` may be *getter/setters* for the matching named argument. This is defined under [step 11.c.ii of 10.6](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6):

> 1. Add *name* as an element of the list *mappedNames*.
> 2. Let *g* be the result of calling the [*MakeArgGetter*](http://es5.github.io/#MakeArgGetter) abstract operation with arguments *name* and *env*.
> 3. Let *p* be the result of calling the [*MakeArgSetter*](http://es5.github.io/#MakeArgSetter) abstract operation with arguments *name* and *env*.
> 4. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of map passing [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8)(indx), the [Property Descriptor](http://es5.github.io/#x8.10) {[[Set]]: *p*, [[Get]]: *g*, [[Configurable]]: **true**}, and **false** as arguments.

As noted in the steps above that, this requires that ***strict** is **false*** and, in this case, that `f` is called with a value for `x`:

```
f()  // undefined, undefined (no argument, no getter/setter)
f(1) // 1, 42
```