# The `arguments` object changes if parameters change

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments

I just discovered that the `arguments` object actually changes if one of the parameters change.

For example:

```
function some(a, b, c ){
  console.log(arguments);


  args = [ a, b, c ];
  a = new Date();

  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(args);
}

some(1,2,3 );
```

You will see that while `args` stays the same (expected behaviour), `arguments` *actually* change.

Questions:

- Is this something that is well documented? If so, where?
- Is there anything else I need to be careful about the `arguments` object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are JavaScript Arguments objects mutated by assignment to parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390539/why-are-javascript-arguments-objects-mutated-by-assignment-to-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specified in the ECMA standard [sec-10.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6):

> For non-strict mode functions [...] the number of formal parameters of
>   the corresponding function object initially share their values with
>   the corresponding argument bindings in the function’s execution
>   context. This means that changing the property changes the
>   corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa. This
>   correspondence is broken if such a property is deleted and then
>   redefined or if the property is changed into an accessor property. For
>   strict mode functions, the values of the arguments object’s properties
>   are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and there is
>   no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal
>   parameter values.

Comment: Wow. What an odd behavior. Thanks for the reference.